# Node.js: How can I mask command line arguments in console.log statements in a script?

Tags: node.js

I noticed this feature when I triggered a Node.js script in my Jenkins pipeline, passing username and password as command line arguments.

The script was being called like this:

```
node myScript.js $CREDENTIALS_USR $CREDENTIALS_PSW
```

Inside the script, there were following log statements:

```
console.log('username', process.argv[2]);
console.log('password', process.argv[3]);
```

However, although username was getting printed correctly, the log statement for password was just displaying `***`. This was very nice because you would not want to display password in console logs. But I didn't understand how it was accomplished. Infact, if I did a log for

```
console.log('password length', process.argv[3].length);
```

It displayed the correct length of the actual password so the password being passed is correct. It is just being displayed as masked value. Where can I set this type of configuration to mask command line arguments from console log statements ?

To give you an example, if the value of `$CREDENTIALS_USR` is `mandeep` and the value of `$CREDENTIALS_PSW` is say `123456` and they are both loaded from Jenkins credentials store, inside the script the following statements will have the output written adjacent to them in comments:

```
console.log('username', process.argv[2]); // this will print mandeep
console.log('password', process.argv[3]); // this will print *** (only 3 stars irrespective of actual length of process.argv[3]
console.log('password length', process.argv[3].length); // this will print 6 because the password was 123456
```

Answer (score 1):

Node does not perform any automatic/implicit masking of any script arguments. Most likely Jenkins is the one passing the literal string '***' as the second argument to your script.

Comment: If I pass the second argument as `123456` and then check the length of this argument in the script it shows the correct length of 6. But if I console log this argument it displays `***` only. So, jenkins is definitely passing some extra info that allows the script to read the password and use it but not display it

Comment: How do you know the script has received an unmasked version of the password? If Jenkins is passing a masked version of the password, the length would match, so that's not exactly proof.

Comment: But how can you say that it's passing a literal string `'***'` ? Because in that case the length should be 3. Correct me if I am wrong. What I want to understand is the mechanism for passing arguments in such a way to a node.js script

Comment: I used that because that was what you used in your original question. The point is it would be the same length as the actual password.